# HTML não reconhece o jQuery (importado ou interno)

Tags: jquery

Já pesquisei diversos tópicos e não encontrei o problema. 
Simplificando, as funções que utilizo no jQuery, como tooltip e mask, não funcionam na minha página, e ao dar f12 no navegador chrome, informa que o jquery não está importado (Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined javascript). Estava utilizando o jquery na maquina, e mudei para o cdn e o problema persiste. Imagino que seja algo relativamente bobo, mas estou a dias tentando resolver o problema.

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Semana da Engenharia</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 **<script src="js/js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>**
 **<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>**
 <!-- responsável pelas funções de máscara em jQuery -->
 **<script src="js/jquery.mask.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>**
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssIndex.css">
 <!-- responsável pelas funções em boostrap -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <!-- responsável por instanciar os icones -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
 <img src="bannerWeek.jpg" id="bannerWeek">

  <div id="divLogin">
   <select required id="comboboxLogin">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione o tipo de usuário</option>
    <option value="administrador">Administrador</option>
    <option value="visitante">Visitante</option>
   </select>
   
   <input type="text" name="senhaUsuario" id="senhaLogin" placeholder="Informe sua senha">
   <span class="iconInPasswordField"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>

   <span id="iconInPasswordField" data-toggle="tooltip"
   title="A sua senha é o seu RA!"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></span>

   <input type="submit" value="ACESSAR" id="btnAcessar" onclick="enviarLogin()">
  </div>

  <span id="edicao2019">6º Edição - 2019</span>
  <span id="unifaeLogo">UNI<span style="color: red">FAE</span></span>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```html
/*responsavel pela mensagem de ajuda "qual minha senha?"
  o que ele faz realmente?*/

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#senhaLogin").mask("99999-9"); 
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});

/* redireciona para a respectiva página de acordo com o usuário*/
function enviarLogin(comboboxLogin) {
 var op = document.getElementById("comboboxLogin").value;

 if(op == "visitante") {
  window.location.href = "userPage.html";
 }
 else
  if (op == "administrador") {
  window.location.href = "admPage.html";
  }
  else
   alert("Informe o tipo de usuário!");
}
```

Comment: Cara suas tags que importam os script devem vir por último no documento. E os scripts que vc escreve devem vir ainda depois desses scripts importados.

Comment: Coloquei todos depois do body (importados e depois o js e css que criei) e nao funcionou :/ 

oloquei tudo depois do body e continua nao funcionando :/ . . . . Inclusive, apareceu novos erros: . . . Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND /////// jquery.mask.min.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'maskWatchers' of undefined /////// at jquery.mask.min.js:15 at jquery.mask.min.js:6 at jquery.mask.min.js:6 ////// bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery at bootstrap.min.js:6 //// js.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at js.js:4 //

Answer (score 2):

Tente remover o atributo `type="text/javascript"` das tags `script` do jQuery. Pode ser isso que esteja impedindo. Aliás, ele não é obrigatório, conforme diz o site [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp), pois o JavaScript é a linguagem padrão de script.

Retirado e adaptado de [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp):

> **Quer saber por que não temos type="text/javascript" dentro da tag `<script>`?**
>
> Isso não é requerido no HTML5. JavaScript é a linguagem padrão de script no HTML5 e em todos os navegadores modernos!

Em um app que eu cheguei a desenvolver, e usar o jQuery, eu não havia colocado o atributo `type="text/javascript"` na hora de importá-lo, e funcionou perfeitamente.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: E aliás, permaneça com as tags de script na head, ou então, coloque-as dentro do body, lá no final. E deixe a tag do `js.js` depois das tags do jQuery, ou de qualquer outra biblioteca, conforme o @Darlei_Fernando_Zillmer e o @hugocsl sugeriram.

Answer (score 2):

Sei que já faz muito tempo que essa pergunta foi postada, mas sempre pode ter alguém tendo a mesma dificuldade. Eu estava tendo o mesmíssimo problema, e no meu caso foi uma coisa idiota... eu simplesmente estava me esquecendo de importar o core do JQuery (o JQuery em si) antes de importar o jquery.mask.min.js. Obviamente, sem o core do JQuery uma biblioteca dependente dele não iria funcionar nunca...

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa forma, basicamente você está chamando o arquivo com as funções antes de adicionar a biblioteca.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Semana da Engenharia</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssIndex.css">
    <!-- responsável pelas funções em boostrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- responsável por instanciar os icones -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <img src="bannerWeek.jpg" id="bannerWeek">

        <div id="divLogin">
            <select required id="comboboxLogin">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione o tipo de usuário</option>
                <option value="administrador">Administrador</option>
                <option value="visitante">Visitante</option>
            </select>

            <input type="text" name="senhaUsuario" id="senhaLogin" placeholder="Informe sua senha">
            <span class="iconInPasswordField"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>

            <span id="iconInPasswordField" data-toggle="tooltip"
            title="A sua senha é o seu RA!"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></span>

            <input type="submit" value="ACESSAR" id="btnAcessar" onclick="enviarLogin()">
        </div>

        <span id="edicao2019">6º Edição - 2019</span>
        <span id="unifaeLogo">UNI<span style="color: red">FAE</span></span>
</body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mask.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
    <script src="js/js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu vi numa página que dizia isso, mas achei que o " $(document).ready(function(){ " funcionaria somente depois que o html fosse carregado

Comment: Note que o "$(document).ready(function(){" está chamando o cifrão do jquery tambem, mas como ele será executado se não foi incluido? Existem outras formas, em js puro de fazer esse "ready", mas só inverta a ordem que já vai funcionar

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, Darlei! Fiz tudo certinho, coloquei tudo depois do body e continua nao funcionando :/
.
.
.
.
Inclusive, apareceu novos erros: 
.
.
.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ///////
jquery.mask.min.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'maskWatchers' of undefined ///////
    at jquery.mask.min.js:15
    at jquery.mask.min.js:6
    at jquery.mask.min.js:6 ///////
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6 ///////
js.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at js.js:4 /////

Comment: Coloca o codigo da mascara para cima tambem, logo depois do jquery e antes do seu js.js. Editei a resposta